# android SimpleDateFormat wrong format android 4.x

Tags: android, time, format

i am having an issue with `SimpleDateFormat` on Android.
Using this code:

```
private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm:ss,S";
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT, Locale.US);
String time = timeFormat.format(time.getTime());
```

`time` has the following format "12:30:25,187" instead of "12:30:25,1".
It happens on 4.x versions only.

Comment: Confirmed on my 4.4 device. I'm not sure if you can do anything about that, other than checking the number of digits after the comma, and lopping off the last two if there's three.

Comment: so far looks the only solution!

Comment: It looks like it's been fixed on 5.x: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78859&can=1&q=simpledateformat%20fractional&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Answer (score 0):

So far this is my solution.

```
String formatted = timeFormat.format(time);
String[] splitted = formatted.split(",");
if(splitted.length > 1) {
    String tenth = splitted[1];
    if(tenth.length() > 1) {
        tenth = tenth.substring(0,1);
        formatted = splitted[0] + "," + tenth;
    }
}
```

Comment: I kinda misspoke in my earlier comment. You don't really need to count, or even split. You can just do: `formatted = formatted.substring(0, formatted.indexOf(",") + 2);`